# Modified objects.all() method in Django model manager is not working in Search view but working fine elsewhere

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have overridden model manager all() method to only return active items from the database. And I can see only active items coming through in normal list view. But when I use the same in Search view if I search something relevant it returns all the items irrespective of the active status.

My ProductManager to override the custom manager methods look like -

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using = self._db)

    def all(self):
        print('all method')
        return self.get_queryset().active()

    def active(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(active = True)

    def featured(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(featured = True)

    def search(self, query):
        lookups = ( Q(title__icontains = query) | 
                    Q(description__icontains = query) |
                    Q(tag__title__icontains = query)
                    
                    )
        return self.filter(lookups).distinct()
```

My custom queryset method:

```
 class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

     def active(self):
            return self.filter(active = True)

     def featured(self):
            return self.filter(featured = True)
```

Class based view for search

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search/view.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
        request = self.request
        qs = Product.objects.all()
        print('QUERY SET==========================')
        print(qs)  
        *******************************************
        Until this point it is working fine only the active items coming
        <ProductQuerySet [<Product: shirt>, <Product: A hat>, <Product: test product>, <Product: One 
        more item>]>
        *******************************************

        print('QUERY SET==========================')
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        #search query can be saved href
        #SearchQuery.objects.create(query=query)
        if query is not None:
            qs = Product.objects.search(query)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
        context = super(SearchListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print('SEARCH CONTEXT',context)
        *******************************
        Here is the problem - If I do an empty search the context data is filled with all the objects 
        irrespective of active and inactive items.

        SEARCH CONTEXT {'paginator': None, 'page_obj': None, 'is_paginated': False, 'object_list': 
        <ProductQuerySet [<Product: shirt>, <Product: shirt>, <Product: A hat>, <Product: Jeans>, 
        <Product: test product>, <Product: One more item>]>, 'product_list': <ProductQuerySet 
         [<Product: shirt>, <Product: shirt>, <Product: A hat>, <Product: Jeans>, <Product: test 
         product>, <Product: One more item>]>, 'view': <search.views.SearchListView object at 
         0x000002AD72EA4748>}
         *********************************

        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

I hope my explanation clear to all. If you need other information, please do let me know.
Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: how did you connect the manager in your model?

Comment: return self.get_queryset().filter(lookups).distinct()

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have added the manager using objects = ProductManager() .

Comment: @Blackdoor Changing the lookups method is not changing anything. 
            return self.get_queryset().filter(lookups).distinct()

Comment: If q is empty string, search can not be called.